# Exchange: User Impersonation not working

Tags: office-365, exchange, exchange-online

I'm trying to achieve impersonation for my Exchange subscription. I am the ADMIN for my tenant. I have followed these steps(http://www.codetwo.com/kb/how-to-set-impersonation-rights-manually/) to grant myself FULL CONTROL over other mail accounts for my tenant.

But when I try to access those through API, I get a 403 forbidden message.

### URL

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/some_other_user@mydomain.com
```

### HEADERS

```
Authorization Bearer asdhasdjasd....
```

### RESPONSE

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
    }
}
```

Following are the permissions that my APP asks for,

[image: Permissions]

What am I doing wrong? I had this working about 6 months back, now when I'm trying it again, it doesn't work!